# PHP system() keeps echo even though

Tags: php, image, file, system

So I need to found out if an upload from a user is images/ video and what type. I currently use

```
"filetype"=>system("file -i -b ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])
```

which is inserted into my MongoDB collection via this

```
$s3file='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
$collection = static::db()->media;
$datetime = time();
$mediaupload = array("owner"=>$_SESSION['user_information'][0]['_id'],"filelink"=>$s3file,"filetype"=>system("file -i -b ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),"filesize"=>$size,"uploadtime"=>$datetime,"ownerid"=>$_SESSION["user_information"][0]['_id']);
$collection->insert($mediaupload);
$media = $collection->findOne($mediaupload);
```

However what I am noticing is it echos the result out to the PHP page - which is not what I need it to do. i know it is the system function because when I remove that function it does not echo the uploaded file type to the php code.

I am wondering therefor how can i still run that system file -i -b function and get it to include into the MongoDB database but not echo the result into the public php page return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like (for multi-line output)

```
exec("file -i -b ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $output);
array("filetype"=>$output);
```

It may look a little unorthodox, but exec uses its second input parameter as a way to pass the output information back to you - the output of `file` will be stored as an array into `$output`.

[From the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

If you simply want the first line from the output, use the simpler version:

```
array("filetype"=>exec("file -i -b ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have switched the system to exec() and that seems to of fixed my issue